# Событие при изменении переменной

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно событие которое выполняется при изменении переменной

Comment: что за событие? какой переменной?

Comment: нет таких событий

Comment: Если речь идет о простых переменных, объявляемых где-либо в коде, то стандартного способа не существует. Однако, можно придумать свой вариант, или взять уже существующий, благо их достаточно ищется по запросу `js event variable change`. Вот наиболее интересные: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396558/watch-variable-changes-in-jquery-javascript)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396558/watch-variable-changes-in-jquery-javascript), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638769/in-javascript-how-to-trigger-event-when-a-variables-value-is-changed)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063

Comment: Можно сделать переменную свойством объекта, и использовать [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Answer (score 4):

Для создания события при изменении значения переменной отлично подходит библиотека FLOSS.js (менее 1кб).

Создать переменную:

```
FLOSS({
 name: 'userName',
 value: 'Petr Soskov',
 action: function(value){ alert(value) },
 defer: true /* отменяю вызов action при создании переменной */
});

console.log(userName); /* Petr Soskov */
userName = 'Ivan Ivanov'; /* alert('Ivan Ivanov'); */
```

При изменении `userName` будет отрабатывать `action`.

Ссылка на [библиотеку](https://github.com/DmitryTitov89/FLOSS).

Comment: эта штука плодит кучу глобальных переменных, что не очень круто и если вы объявите две с одинаковым `name`, то будут проблемы

Answer (score 3):

Для отслеживания изменения можно использовать следующие варианты решения:

1. Объект proxy. Он позволяет перехватывать обращение к другому объекту. Однако данный метод реализован лишь в спецификации ES-2015.
2. Можно так же попытаться использовать Object.defineProperty. Как и с proxy - все это работа со свойствами объектов,. Необходимо быть осторожны, что бы не вызывать бесконечную рекурсию.
3. Существует готовое решение: FLOSS.js
4. И наконец, можно реализовать узконаправленный функционал, для решения поставленной задачи:

```js
    var name = 'Boris';

    let changeName = newName => {
       name = newName;
       console.log('New name: ' + name);
    }

    changeName('Petr');
```

Comment: Да, этот вопрос я задавал давно. Сейчас понял что есть геттеры и сеттеры.